# Large json, store two fields in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-cloud-firestore

I have a large json file that needs to have to "fields" merged in to an array in order to store to firestore.

Here a screenshot to show what I mean. What i have:

[image: Status Quo]
What I need:
[image: What I need]

As you can see GRP1D and GRP2D where merged in to an array. The json has 15000 entries so doing it manually is not an option

Comment: When asking question on StackOverflow, you should at least try to show what have you tried so far... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is small code snippet using the spread operator

```
const your_data = require("./your_data/ file/path");
const prepare_func = (your_data)=>{
  let temp = {...your_data,"GRP1D":[your_data["GRP1D"],your_data["GRP2D"]]};
  return temp;
}
let new_data = prepare_func(your_data);
```

Comment: @landyandolt yes

Comment: in the {} brackets, do I add the path to my file? That doesnt really work. I dont have to replace every "your_data" just define your data the first time.

Comment: I have edited the code now just add your file path over here 
require("./your_data/ file/path");

Comment: Thanks! How can I make it create a new file or change the data directly in the largejson fiie?
I tried "new_data = require('new_data');
new_data.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8', callback)" but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script using NodeJS to edit this huge file similar to the following:

```js
const largeJson = require('./largeJson.json');

// I am assuming here that the large JSON file is an array of objects
const mergedJson = largeJson.map(obj => {
    const objEditted = { ...obj, GRP1D: [ obj.GRP1D, obj.GRP2D ] };
    delete objEditted.GRP2D;  

    return objEditted;
});

// mergedJson now holds an array of objects which merge the fields 
// GRP1D and GRP2D as you described in the example
```

Comment: Thanks!
However, I get an error "Unexpected token : in JSON at position 3320"

at that position in the json file, nothing seems to be wrong. Also, at largeJson.map I should just put in the name of the json file, right? It wont take the path

Comment: To add to the error above "at parse (<anonymous>)" is also part of the message

Comment: Just in case, can you validate the JSON file [here](https://jsonlint.com/)?

Comment: The error is TypeError: largeJson.map is not a function

Comment: How can I make the script change the large jason file directly, or maybe create a new file?
I tried to add "mergedJson = require('mergedJson');
mergedJson.writeFile('myjsonfile.json', json, 'utf8',
 callback)" but nothing happens. And the error "largeJson.map is not a function" still stands in the way.